# Convergence of Functions Real Analysis

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Can someone explain how to attack this proofs please.  I am studying maths and cannot understand this.

For each $n \in N$, suppose that $f_n \colon [a,b] \to R$ is some function, such that the sequence $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to some function $f$. For each $n \in N$, define $F_n \colon [a,b] \to R$ by
$$F_n(x)= \int_a^x f_n(t)\,dt.$$
Similarly, define $F \colon [a,b] \to R$ by
$$F(x)= \int_a^x f(t)\,dt.$$
Prove that the sequence $\{F_n\}$ converges uniformly to $F$.

Comment: You want to estimate the difference $|F(x) - F_n(x)|$ using the fact that $|f(x) - f_n(x)|$ is small. Can you think of a way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ with sequence?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your questions.  Other people may find them useful in the future.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Note that
$$
\left\lvert F_n(x)-F(x)\right\rvert=\left\lvert\int_a^x(f_n(t)-f(t))\,dt\right\rvert\leq\int_a^x\left\lvert f_n(t)-f(t)\right\rvert\,dt\leq\int_a^b\left\lvert f_n(t)-f(t)\right\rvert\,dt
$$
for every $x\in[a,b]$.  (Why?  There are a couple of things to justify there; particularly, the last step.)

Now, you can make $\left\lvert f_n(t)-f(t)\right\rvert$ small *uniformly* over $t\in[a,b]$ by choosing $n$ sufficiently large.  So...